# Selenium Webdriver Onlink Text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What command in webdriver should I use to make sure it clicks the specific text i.e **Last Month**

the code is

```
<div class="dt_padded_medium_div">
<a onclick="setLastMonth()" href="#">Last Month</a>
```

I tried xpath by using firepath but still doesnt work
it was

```
 //*[@id='block-2']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]
```

I used

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='block-2']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]")).click();
```

but still didnt work, am I missing something?

**Update:**

**Got the Code working guys, thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one 'a' element in the page with this text, try this XPath:

```
//a[text()='Last Month']
```

If there are more than one element, please, post the full HTML tree else we're unable to write a xpath without know the tag path and ensure it will work

Comment: Thanks Striter I used that method and it worked, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your xpath works correctly, try to use more specific xpath other than just td[5] or smthn like that, for example above could be like:
`//div[@class='dt_padded_medium_div']/a[@href]` - meaning, we need to find `<div>` element with specific parent and within it `<a>` element that has `href` property

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your xPath is correct?

Install **FirePath** on Firefox and experiment with your xPath as on screenshot below.

Also, that does look like a long and brittle xPath. Look up [xPath cheat sheets](https://www.google.cz/search?q=selenium%20xpath%20cheat%20sheet&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji8IWw7qrNAhWBFxQKHcuIA8kQ_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=955) to learn how to make your xPath more robust.

In your case I would imagine something like:

```
 //*[@id='block-2']/descendant::a[text()='Last Month']
```

(get the element with a particular ID, then search for an `<a></a>` in that element, no matter how deep, with a particular text)

[image]

Comment: Please share your solution ;)

Comment: Strangely enough I had firebug running the entire time and even using the specific xpath for the text it still didnt work. So I used 'driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Last Month']")).click();'

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you have used a "id" that is not shown in your code, where is **@id='block-2'**. It is possible for you to have used the wrong id. For us to help you, can you please provide the whole HTML code?

What I can suggest based on the information you have provided is:

Making sure the Xpath you have provided is unique, there is an add-on for Firefox called **Firebug** you can use. It will help you find out the xpath you are after fast and easy. What you need to do is basically:

- download firefox and install it;
- download firebug add-on and install it to firefox;
- you will notice there is a small bug symbol to the top right of your tool bar, please enable it;
- you will see a console pops out, click on inspection button and click on any web element you want to inspect and its html code will be highlighted in the console;
- right click on the highlighted code and choose to copy its xpath to clipboard. This way you will never get your xpath wrong.

Here is a quick tutorial:
http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug

P.S. There are more than one way to locate a webelement, please consider using the following options as well:

- Css selector
- class name
- id

This link will direct you to an awesome cheat cheet.
http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you greatly for the information, will definitely use this for future reference! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code to click on the text **Last Month**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Last Month']")).click();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Karthik, used your code and it worked. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey Karthik is it possible to ask you another question about selenium webdriver command?

Comment: Yes please.. u can ask. But as per the rules you need to start new thread for the question i guess.. :)

Comment: Have you asked the question. If so can you please give me the link

Comment: yes I have, here you go
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928008/selenium-webdriver-html-code)

Comment: hey karthik heres a better link for it  [Xpath question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948644/selenium-webdriver-xpath-not-working_)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to click on the link containing the text 'Last Month'

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Last Month")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities. 
If you're site doesn´t get rewritten to much you could just go for the link name via

```
driver.findElement(By.linkName("Last Month");
```

You could also go for any of the attributes if your site is subject of many rewrites like this and just put "href" and "#" or "onclick" and "setLastMonth()" as arguments when calling it.

```
static WebElement getLink(String Attribute, String Value /*String ItemText*/){
List<WebElement> Elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for(int Counter = 0, Counter < Elements.size(); Counter++){
        if(Elements.get(Counter).getAttribute(Attribute).contains(Value) /* && Elements.get(Counter).getText().equals(ItemText){
            return Elements.get(Counter);
        }
    }
return null;
}
```

If you remove the comments it will go completely sure and check for the Attributes and the displayed text.

Comment: Thank you for the information I got it work but really do appreciate the help!!