# Selenium WebDriver HTML Code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[This is what the error displays when I use the xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svqps.png)

[image: Xpath]What command on the selenium webdriver would I use to click a text which has a xpath of

```
html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a
```

I tried using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a")).click();
```

but still doesn't work... any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: doesnt execute the command using that xpath

Comment: used 'driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a")).click();' but still didnt work @alecxe

Comment: Make sure your xpath is correct, if  could post your markup that would be helpful

Comment: @MoH. just added the html code for the xpath and yes double checked the xpath is right

Comment: This markup is malformed, your `div`s never end

Comment: And that xpath does not match that html code

Comment: @MoH. just added the picture, its the correct xpath

Comment: and the code loads the browser and navigates correctly?

Comment: @MoH. yes it does when I click it... works perfectly fine but when I type it on selenium webdriver.. the code you suggested below... says "Unable to locate element"

Comment: But does it navigate to the page correctly before the click? And what does your original code do?

Comment: Yes the page on the dashboard loads perfectly fine its just a matter of clicking that offer at the bottom of the page and loading the clicked offer... just the xpath wont work when put into the webdriver @MoH.

Comment: Please include the error and stack trace for your original code in your question

Comment: @MoH. posted the error msg in the question

Comment: This is for the new code.... Please include it for your original code

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is incorrect. You are trying to hit an absolute path with `html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a`. You are missing a `/` so instead it should be `/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a`

try:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a")).click();`

Comment: tried it still doesnt work ... it displays "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a"}"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using absolute xpath which is not reliable way to identify an element, you can try this: `//input[@id='partnerId']/following-sibling::a`. It finds an element with unique id and then locates nearest sibling having tag `a`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issues when the element to be located was in a separate iframe.

Using FirePath or source html, check if there are any iframes and if yes, use 

driver.switchTo().frame("framename") 
and then use

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIvKF.png)/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a")).click();

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about just using `By.linkText()` or  `By.partialLinkText()` instead of XPath? Using XPath in this way is "easy" but very fragile I would recommend against it.

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("EARN up to "));
```

You can, of course, edit the partial link text to be more or less specific depending on what you are looking for and how unique the text is on the page.

---

Since that didn't work, let's try a different approach. Let's find all the links in the table you have pictured above. The code below will grab the A tags in the table and then click the first one. My guess from the picture is that the text contained in the link will likely change so having a more flexible way to find the links is better than using the link text. See if the below works.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.data-block-sub-popular-offers > div.row-heading > a"));
links[0].click();
```

Comment: Hey jeff tried using partial and linktext... still didnt work .. used 'driver.findElement(By.linkText("EARN up to 2.5% on g...")).click();' and your partial link one..

Comment: gives me an error of **Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"EARN up to 2.5% on g..."}**

Comment: Updated my answer with another approach. See if that works. I think it's more flexible if it still fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

just use xpath below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row-40percent']/a[contains(text(),'Earn upto 2.5%')]").click();
```