# Selenium Webdriver Xpath not working

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to click a link text using selenium webdriver but is not working,

Here are the pictures

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8f42.png)

[Offer Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beidi.png)

On firefox using firebug I got the xpath

```
html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a
```

I used

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a")).click();`

but still doesnt work, any reason to why?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons. Some that come to mind: 1) your HTML screenshot says something about iframe; are there indeed frames involved with your scenario? 2) any XPath that starts with "html" is not optimized correctly, and is almost guaranteed to be brittle.

Comment: Checked and there are no iFrames in the code at all... tried using 'driver.findelement(By.name)' and still didnt work

Comment: Please clarify "doesnt work"!

Comment: When I tried the 'driver.findelement(By.name)', the message says cannot locate element,name...Also am confused as to why the xpath starts with "body"

Comment: What name did you use? From looking at your HTML, I do not see any name attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I see name attribute in your html code but the element type is hidden.Selenium doesn't interact with hidden elements.Try using other path like "`//input[@id='offerId']/..//a`"

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question in comment-4, there are two ways in which we can write xpath.

1. Relative xpath: This xpath starts with "//", which indicates, search for the element from a particular position in the DOM
2. Absolute xpath: This xpath start with `html/body`, which indicates, search for the element from the first tag of the DOM

Relative xpath search is faster than Absolute xpath search, as it searches from the particular position in the document not from the root of the DOM.

Coming to your main question:

Can you please try using below code:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='HTML CODE']"))` and `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Offer Selection']"))`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: do I have to use both or just one of the code you provided? And would it be 'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='EARN up to 2.5% on g...']")).click();'

Comment: You can use the xpath which identifies the respective element on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to click on the link using the partial link text.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("EARN up to 2.5% on")));
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("EARN up to 2.5% on")).click();
```